# Custom span calculation in lucene

Tags: lucene

I have written a plugin in lucene which annotates certain terms and stores their spans in this fashion `<term>,<span>;<term>,<span>;..`

Now i need to handle span near queries just using these spans and not the default lucene stored spans. This is because not all terms which are similar are annotated. So basically if i query terms within k tokens, then i should be able to get their span distance by subtracting their corresponding spans. How will i be able to do this in lucene? I'm a newbie, so please be as descriptive as possible.

Thanks,
Ananth.

Answer (score 0):

A good general rule I follow in Lucene is to put specially-processed data into its own fields so there is little chance of a mix-up. In that way, you can perform your nearness queries in the way you want. (This will make your index bigger.)

Comment: Hi Mark, the annotations are being stored in seperate fields, but i didn't get how this will help us to calculate span? For e.g. here's a text `Microsoft has its headquarters in Redmond`. Lucene has one field called `company` that has the term `Microsoft,0` and another field called `hq` that has the term `Redmond,5`. Since these are different fields altogether, lucene's nearness queries won't help right? So how do i do this distance calculation in an adhoc manner? Not sure if i explained it properly. Do let me know if i wasn't lucid.